# Get the calling object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using `websocket` from node, and I am trying to implement a `broadcast` method that will send a message to all clients except for the client that sent the message.

To do this, I need to know the

```
export class WebSocketRoom {

  private _clients: WebSocketConnection[] = []
  public get clients(): WebSocketConnection[] { return this._clients }

  public broadcast(event: string, message: any) {
    this.clients.forEach(client => {
      client.emit(event, message)
    })
    return this
  }
}
```

To access the method `broadcast`, I do this:

```
class Test extends Module {
  public constructor(client: WebSocketConnection) {
    super(client)

    let room = new WebSocketRoom('hi')
    room.broadcast('cool', 'sweet')

  }
}
```

I tried doing a console log of `WebSocketRoom.caller` but that gives me this error:

> TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function properties and cannot be accessed in this context.

Is there a way that I can access the object that called `broadcast` from within the `broadcast` method without passing it as a parameter?

```
this.clients.forEach(client => {
  if(client == sender) return
  client.emit(event, message)
})
```

#### Side note

In C#, it is done like so:

```
public static void MyMethod(this GameObject obj, int var1, int var2) {
    obj.add(var1, var2)
}

MyMethod(1,2)
```

As you can see obj is not passed in when it is called.

Comment: fwiw, it's a bit of an anti-pattern; you should be consuming the same events on all clients, even the sender. this prevents double-coding handler/view updaters and makes the view more authoritative.

Comment: I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand why you are having trouble with this. Why would you add `this` to the `clients` array? If you avoid exposing the array of clients, and instead expose a method for adding new clients to the array, then you can do your check within this method. On the other hand, I cannot immediately see why you would want to design this in a way that allows `this` to be added to that array; it makes no sense to me. If adding `this` to the array is allowed, then doesn't that mean you should not prevent it from being called in broadcast?

Comment: I'm not sure where you see `this` getting added to an array...